# Spring Roo finder by ID

Tags: spring-roo

What is the best way to create a finder using Spring MVC/Roo  that will search on the ID field?   Finder List command doesnt pick up on ID as it auto-generated and wasnt created as a field as part of the entity

Answer (score 0):

`repo.find(...)` does a find by ID

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID, you are technically reading the object, not "finding it" per se.  Solubris is almost right.  However, the correct repository method for reading is `repo.findOne(ID)`.